# Scrolling vertically and paging horizontally in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

i have a number of pages, that have content larger than the screen i.e the user has to scroll down to see more of the content.  These pages are inside a ViewPager.  For the life of me i can't figure out how to make the vertical scrolling work.

Just to be clear, i don't want to page to another page vertically just scroll down inside a single page.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  Searching doesn't yield anything, but i'd be surprised if this isn't a common thing to do?

What i've tried:

1. Wrapping a scrollview around a linear layout that holds a view pager and other views.
2. Different combinations of layouts and layout params.

Thanks

As per suggestion, i've taken the example from AndroidHive, so my fragment xml is below, it has enough content that it doesn't fit the screen.  So i'd expect to be able to scroll down similar to a list view to see the rest of the content.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text2"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text3"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text4"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text5"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text6"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text7"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text8"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text9"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I haven't changed anything else from the example code.

Comment: Your Scrollview tag isn't closed.

Comment: Sorry it's incorrectly copied, it is in fact closed correctly

Comment: Relative Layout arranges viewgroup relative to each other.
You can make a text be arranged left of another text view
In  your example,a simple solution would be using Linear Layout instead. So, that each text view is arranged bottom of each other

[Read More] (http://androidexample.com/Relative_Layout_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=73)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use Scrollview insde the fragments in your viewpager.

The fragments in the viewpager should provide the desired horizontal paging and scroll view inside the fragment provides the vertical.

> Fragment One

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class OneFragment extends Fragment{


public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}
}
```

> Layout for Fragment One

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/one"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Androidhive has a simple tutorial** http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Thank you.  I managed to get this working by using NestedScrollView, and the CoordinaterView.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using fragments? Create a separate fragment XML file with your page layout inside a scroll view...

```xml
<!-- fragment_layout.xml -->
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width='match_parent'
    android:layout_height='match_parent'
    ...>
    <WhateverYourPageLayoutIs
        android:layout_width='match_parent'
        android:layout_height='wrap_content'
        .../>
</ScrollView>
```

Then create a Fragment subclass that uses this layout and use a FragmentPagerAdapter (or FragmentStatePagerAdapter) to populate the view pager.